# php session vars

Tags: php, session

I'm working on news archive page for my website, search over archive is done with start date, end date and news category as search parameters. Form values are stored in $_SESSION var, and then they are passed around as an array for pagination and other purposes.
My question would be how to prevent displaying search results on main archive search page if user for some reason goes again to it to make a new search.

here's the code

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //get data from the form
    $archFld_1 = $_POST['archiveFld1'];
    $archFld_2 = $_POST['archiveFld2'];
    $archFld_3 = $_POST['archiveFld3'];
   //just some check on fields
   if (strlen($archFld_1) > 10) { $archFld_1 = ""; }
   if (strlen($archFld_2) > 10) { $archFld_2 = ""; }
   //save them as a array and store to session var
   $_archValues = array($archFld_3, $archFld_1, $archFld_2);
   $_SESSION['storeValues'] = $_archValues;
}
if (isset($_SESSION['storeValues'])) {
    //check params for search
    //set cat for query
    if ($_SESSION['storeValues'][0] > 0) { $valCat = "AND newsCat=".     $_SESSION['storeValues'][0] ." "; } else { $valCat = ""; }
    //set date for query
    if(($_SESSION['storeValues'][1] != "" ) && ($_SESSION['storeValues'][2] == "")) {
        $DateStart = $_SESSION['storeValues'][1];
        $valDate = " AND STR_TO_DATE(newsDate, '%d-%m-%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('$DateStart', '%d-%m-%Y') ";
    }
    if(($_SESSION['storeValues'][2] != "") && ($_SESSION['storeValues'][1]=="")) {
        $DateEnd = $_SESSION['storeValues'][2];
        $valDate = " AND STR_TO_DATE(newsDate, '%d-%m-%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('$DateEnd', '%d-%m-%Y') ";
    }
    if(($_SESSION['storeValues'][1]!="") && ($_SESSION['storeValues'][2] != "")) {
        $DateStart = $_SESSION['storeValues'][1];
        $DateEnd = $_SESSION['storeValues'][2];
        $valDate = " AND STR_TO_DATE(newsDate, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$DateStart', '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('$DateEnd', '%d-%m-%Y') ";
    }
    //query string and stire it to session
    $archQuery_string = $valCat.$valDate;
    $_SESSION['storeQuery'] = $archQuery_string;
}
//pagination start
$page = $_GET['id'];
$perPage = 10;
$result = wbQuery("SELECT * FROM wb_news WHERE newsLang=1 ". $_SESSION["storeQuery"] ."ORDER BY newsId DESC"); 
$totalPages = mysql_num_rows($result);
if(!$page)
$page = 1;
$start = ($page - 1)*$perPage;
?>
    <div id="sps_middle">
        <div class="sps_cnt">
            <div id="sps_middle_ly1">
                <div class="sps_cnt_small">
                    <div class="sps_page_title"><h3><?php echo $wb_lng['txtArchiveTitle']; ?></h3></div>
                        <div class="sps_pages_cnt" style="padding-top: 10px; float: left; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                            <div class="sps_middle_col01">
                                <div style="float: left;">
                                <p>
                                    <?php echo $wb_lng['txtArchiveInfo']; ?>
                                </p>
                                    <form action="<?php $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post" name="archiveForm" class="archiveForm">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <input name="archiveFld1" type="text" id="archiveFld1" value="<?php echo $wb_lng['txtArhivaFld_01']; ?>" />
                                                <input name="archiveFld2" type="text" id="archiveFld2" value="<?php echo $wb_lng['txtArhivaFld_02']; ?>" />
                                                <select name="archiveFld3">
                                                    <option value="0"><?php echo $wb_lng['txtArhivaFld_07']; ?></option>
                                                    <option value="0" ><?php echo $wb_lng['txtArhivaFld_06']; ?></option>
                                                    <option value="1"><?php echo $wb_lng['txtArhivaFld_03']; ?></option>
                                                    <option value="2"><?php echo $wb_lng['txtArhivaFld_04']; ?></option>
                                                    <option value="3"><?php echo $wb_lng['txtArhivaFld_05']; ?></option>
                                                </select>
                                            </li>
                                            <li style="float: right;">
                                                <input name="reset" type="reset" class="sps_archiveform_btn" value="<?php echo $wb_lng['txtArchiveFormReset']; ?>"/>
                                                <input name="submit" type="submit" class="sps_archiveform_btn" value="<?php echo $wb_lng['txtArchiveFormSend']; ?>"/>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <hr />
<?php
if (#HERE GOES SOME CODE TO PERFORM THE CHECK!!!#) {
    //perform db query
    $result = wbQuery("SELECT * FROM wb_news WHERE newsLang=1 ". $_SESSION['storeQuery'] ."ORDER BY newsId DESC LIMIT $start, $perPage"); 
    //count rows
    $totalnews = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $count = 1;
    if($totalnews == 0) {
        //no results, say to the user
        echo "\t\t\t<div class=\"cil_news_text_big\">\n\t\t\t\t".$wb_lng['txtArchiveNoEntries']."\n\t\t\t</div>\n";
    } else {
        //we have results, yeeeeeeeeey
        while($ROWnews = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
            //set link extensions by the news cat
            switch ($ROWnews->newsCat) {
                case 1:
                    $newsCat_link = "news";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $newsCat_link = "statements";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $newsCat_link = "events";
                    break;
            }
            //text summary
            if (strlen($ROWnews->newsShort) > 0 ) {$newsShortTxt = strip_tags($ROWnews->newsShort);
                if ($lang_id==2) { $newsShortTxt =  wbTranslit($newsShortTxt); }
            } else {
                $newsShortTxt = strip_tags($ROWnews->newsFull);
                if ($lang_id==2) { $newsShortTxt = wbTranslit($newsShortTxt); }
            }
            $newsShortTxt = wbShorTxt($newsShortTxt, 210, "... <a title=\"".$wb_lng['txtShowMore']."\" href=\"http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".$lang_link."/".$newsCat_link."/".$ROWnews->newsId."/full/\">".$wb_lng['txtShowMore']."...</a>");
            //show news
            echo "\t\t<div class=\"sps_news_list\">\n";
            echo "\t\t<div class=\"sps_news_l\">\n";
            echo "\t\t\t<img alt=\"\" src=\"http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/content/images/news/_thumb/".$ROWnews->newsImageThumb."\" />\n";
            echo "\t\t</div>";
            echo "\t\t<div class=\"sps_news_r\">\n";
            //transliterate title
            if ($lang_id==2) { $newsTitle =  wbTranslit($ROWnews->newsTitle); } else { $newsTitle =  $ROWnews->newsTitle; } 
            echo "\t\t\t<div class=\"sps_news_title\">\n\t\t\t\t<a title=\"".$newsTitle."\" href=\"http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".$lang_link."/".$newsCat_link."/".$ROWnews->newsId."/full/\">".$newsTitle."</a>\n\t\t\t</div>\n";
            echo "\t\t\t<div class=\"sps_news_date\">\n\t\t\t\t".$ROWnews->newsDate."\n\t\t\t</div>\n";
            echo "\t\t\t<div class=\"sps_news_text_sh\">\n\t\t\t\t".$newsShortTxt."\n\t\t\t</div>\n";
            echo "\t\t</div>";
            echo "\t\t</div>";
            //show <hr /> based on $count
            if($totalnews != $count) { echo "\t\t\t<hr />\n"; }
            $count++;
        }
    }
//pagination check
if($totalPages>$perPage) {
?>
                                <hr />
                                <div class="sps_pagginate">
                                   <?PHP wbPageTurnFront($PHP_SELF."/".$lang_link."/archive/", $totalPages, $page, $perPage); ?>
                                </div>
<?php 
    }
}
?>
```

Any ideas?
Tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

If user goes to make it a new search then you can clear the session at that time.

```
unset($_SESSION['storeValues']);
```

Comment: wouldn't that disable pagination?

Comment: the problem is when user goes to the starting page, search results are shown.